# Seeing strange character for apostrophe on wordpress based page, but only in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, wordpress, content-management-system, content-management, character-entities

I'm gettign this strange character instead of an apostrophe on a page that's powered by Wordpress, but only in Internet Explorer. Other browsers (chrome, firefox) display as the actual apostrophe.

**â€™**

Can somebody tell me what the problem is?

Here's the instance in question: http://cure.org/about/management-team/

You'll see under Dale Brantner, 4th staff member from the top, there in the first paragraph of his bio the word **organization's** and that is the instance which in IE I'm getting the above symbol instead of an apostrophe.

I have tried both with the apostrophy character, and with the HTML character entity `&apos;` but both seem to yield this strange character string. Interestingly, I have noticed it on other wordpress powered blogs from time to time.

Also of note, this page is generated by a custom use of the links function in wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a known issue, you should use `&#39;` instead of `&apos;`

http://www.digimantra.com/tips/how-to-display-apos-in-internet-explorer-ie/

Comment: I have tried both. It appears that wordpress is automatically converting my HTML character entities to the apostrophe in the database because after I hit submit from the dashboard and go back into the record, the HTML code is gone and an apostrophe is there.

Comment: Actually - upon second glance - although the dashboard is showing it to me with the apostrophe, IE is not displaying correctly, so apparently it's got the correct code in the database.

Comment: wow I must be old... W3C doesn't even have &apos; anymore: http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/sgml/entities.html I'm scared now.. what does htmlspecialchars() return?

Answer (score 1):

What you are quoting (`â€™`) almost always is due to an encoding problem, but I get `&apos;` in both IE 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an encoding error. Check that the character encoding settings are the same in both browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use `&#39;` for apostrophes. It's weird, but the same will happen on YouTube when you input an apostrophe...sometimes. Just happened to me earlier when I posted a comment. When I searched `&#39;` on Google, it turns out it just translates to an apostrophe. So, in summary, use `&#39;`.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the apostrophe with `&apos;` if it's still shows up weird it probably a corrupt font.

Comment: If you read the whole question you'll see I have tried that. Thank you anyway.

Comment: are you using utf-8? 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />