# Strange characters appearing in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm having a niggling wordpress problem

Whenever i'm adding an Apostrophe to a wordpress post I create

`'`

Its saving as a strange set of characters

`â€™`

I've used wordpress many times, never encountered this problem

I've uninstalled every single plugin, and the problem remains

I read somewhere to comment out these lines in `wp-config.php` but it doesn't help for new posts

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
//define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Can someone help me? DO need to set the Charset to override somewhere? How??

Comment: Is it saving in DB as â€™ or are they just displayed as that?

Comment: Ah! getting somwhere! I checked the Database and sure enough funny characters are there too. Now what?  Thank you so so much for responding!

Comment: Not sure if this would help but found similar question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610098/seeing-strange-character-for-apostrophe-on-wordpress-based-page-but-only-in-int

Comment: @user850010 I saw that post already, It doesnt help me

Comment: What about this? http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets

Comment: @user850010 I wish I knew what part of that page was helpful to my problem I've read through it, but cannot fathom it

Comment: What does phpMyAdmin say which charset is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to update the thread, as follows.
I followed just about every tutorial out there addressing utf-8 mismatch, nothing helped
Finally we spotted some phishing code had been injected into the root index file (also linked  to some 3rd party adult site, but our site was not redirecting ,
Needless to say, we cleaned that up 
Many thanks for everyone for helping, especially @user850010 I hope This thread will be useful for others

Comment: So the phishing code was in index.php and it changed charset? Anyway +1 for the useful information.

Comment: @user850010 and a billion +1's for you! to me you're more than just a number!! I'm very grateful to you

Answer (score 1):

If that strange character is stored in DB, then it seems that your DB is not set up with the UTF8 charset, so you can uncomment those 2 lines in wp-config.php, since they are not the source of the problem.

You have a comprehensive tutorial how to convert Character Sets with [WordPress Database](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets) but here is the short list what to do:

- Make a backup of your DB
- Maybe it would be better make a copy of your site on your local computer and try the below changes there
- Convert DB (this will not affect existing tables, just those future new created tables)

  ALTER DATABASE MyDb CHARACTER SET utf8;
- convert any tables in the database that are not already in the desired format.

  Focus on the tables **wp_posts** and **wp_postmeta**

  ALTER TABLE wp_posts CHARACTER SET utf8

  ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta CHARACTER SET utf8
- individually alter each column of each table to use the correct
  the character set. This is not a simple process, read carefully the section of above link [regarding columns](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets#Changing_the_charset_of_individual_columns).

Comment: I tried following that, namely ALTER DATABASE MyDb CHARACTER SET utf8;

convert any tables in the database that are not already in the desired format.

Focus on the tables wp_posts and wp_postmeta

ALTER TABLE wp_posts CHARACTER SET utf8

ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta CHARACTER SET utf8 but to no avail, though I do feel we're on the way to solving!! Thanks

Comment: Try opening some post in editor that contains that strange character and replace it with apostrophe and save that post. Does the apostrophe get saved correctly now?

Comment: In the editor, everything seems ok, its only when i am viewing front end that this problem is occurring . thank you

Comment: in myPHPAdmin, your your DB,Tables,Columns should say UTF-8 and also your website should use UTF-8. View one of the page with this problem and then look into the generated source code. In the beginning (in the head tag) what charset is used? For my site I have <meta charset="UTF-8" />. You could also view source code when you are in editor, to check what charset is used there.

Comment: Also check .htaccess file. It is also possible that some non UTF-8 charset is set there. http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setting-charset-in-htaccess.html

Comment: Hi, hoping to revive this thread a little as I'm running into a very similar issue.  I am currently still getting those symbols along with with some garbled text "ì›¨ì´ë¸Œíˆ¬ì–´ìŠ¤" when I view my site in a browser.  However, in my database, when I view through PHPMyAdmin, the characters (which are korean) are showing up correctly.  My database is set to utf8 encoding, and all appears well until my server sends the characters to the browser.  The HTML output by the server just contains that garbled text.  The encoding is present in the HTML.  I can't figure out why.

Answer (score -1):

Run this query:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDb CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

After edit *wp_config.php* and set:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```